# Missing metaclass in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do you override a model's metaclass in Django 1.5? I was overriding the metaclass on some models inheriting from an abstract model so I could set appropriate choices. e.g.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    field_with_choices = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModelMetaClass(BaseModel.__metaclass__):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super(MyModelMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        field = new_class._meta.get_field('field_with_choices')
        choices = field._choices = []
        choices.extend(get_choices())
        return new_class

class MyModel(BaseModel):

    __metaclass__ = MyModelMetaClass
```

However, when I upgraded to Django 1.5, I now get the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'BaseModel' has no attribute '__metaclass__'
```

How do you override a model's metaclass in 1.5, or otherwise dynamically set field attributes in model subclasses?

Comment: the python versions are the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `built-in` function `type` like this:

```
class MyModelMetaClass(type(BaseModel)):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_class = super(MyModelMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        field = new_class._meta.get_field('field_with_choices')
        choices = field._choices = []
        choices.extend(get_choices())
        return new_class
```

Although I see that `type(ModelBase) is type` so you basically could inherit from `type` or maybe from `Model.__metaclass__` which is in turn `ModelBase` so `ModelBase` is the top of the Model metaclass architecture (before `type` of course :D ).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, thanks. I thought the solution would be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, django 1.5 is using [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) for compatibility management. According to the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass), the proper way would be the following:

```
from six import with_metaclass

class Meta(type):
    pass

class Base(object):
    pass

class MyClass(with_metaclass(Meta, Base)):
    pass
```