# Is it possible to change the name of a class (type) with a python decorator?

Tags: python, django, class, python-decorators

I'm trying to autocode 100's of database table models by decorating my Django (ORM) models (class definitions) to derive their class names from the file name.  But I think my "depth of decoration" is too shallow. Do I need a function `def` or class definition within my `__call__` method? Can it not be done with something simple like this?

```
# decorators.py
import os
from inspect import get_module

class prefix_model_name_with_filename(object):
    'Decorator to prefix the class __name__ with the *.pyc file name'

    def __init__(self, sep=None):
        self.sep = sep or ''

    def __call__(self, cls):
        model_name = os.path.basename(getmodule(cls).__file__).split('.')[0]
        setattr(cls, '__name__', model_name + self.sep + getattr(cls, '__name__'))
        return cls
```

Example usage of the decorator

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
import decorators

@decorators.prefix_model_name_with_filename
class ShipMeth(models.Model):
    ship_meth = models.CharField(max_length=1, primary_key=True)
```

The model doesn't exist in the module definition with the new name and I can't use it without it looking in the decorator class (rather than the model class) to find attributes!

```
>>> from sec_mirror.models import ShipMeth
>>> ShipMeth.__name__

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/Hobson/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 ShipMeth.__name__

AttributeError: 'prefix_model_name_with_filename' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Do I need to decorate the module somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that's the work for a metaclass:

```
import os

def cls_changer(name, parents, attrs):
    model_name = os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0]
    return type(model_name+name, parents, attrs)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = cls_changer
    pass

print A.__name__
```

The previous example just create new classes with the name changed but if you want your module to reflect the changes you need to this (Note my python script is named **untitled0.py**):

```
import os

def cls_changer(name, parents, attrs):
    model_name = os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0]
    res = type(model_name+name, parents, attrs)
    gl = globals()
    gl[model_name+name] = res
    return res

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = cls_changer
    pass

print A.__name__
print untitled0A
```

Output:

```
untitled0A
<class '__main__.untitled0A'>
```

Comment: Probably, but I can't figure out how to use the `__metaclass__` method to help me "instantiate" the 100+ classes (with unique names).

Comment: Humm, could you just do the same as in the example I've posted?. I mean:class `class ShipMeth(models.Model): \n __metaclass__ = cls_changer`

Comment: Well, I've just noted that you use Django!! Maybe this approach won't help you 'cause Django uses metaclasses too!! So if you change it maybe you will mess it up! Try and let me know ;)

Comment: Did try it and Django allows your metaclass to happily change the `__name__` attribute, but still no joy on the type name available in the module. I still have to import it using the old ShipMeth name.  I'll try it on a regular (nonDjango) class and module to see if that gets closer.

Comment: Also, I had to wrap your `model_name + name` with `str`s to convert from unicode to ascii (py2.7 `str`). It seems that py2.7 `os.path` uses unicode since it has to deal with the OS.  Here's the fix: `return type(str(model_name) + str(name), parents, attrs)`

Comment: Even in a non-Django python module, changing `__name__` with the metaclass as you did fails to modify the name that the module uses to present it to you on import. I still have to use, e.g. `print A` instead of `import modulefilename` and `print modulefilename.modulefilenameA`.

Comment: I've found the solution to your problem check the edit to the answer

Comment: Awesome! Testing it now.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Once I override Django's model metaclass per [stackoverflow.com/a/16552927/623735](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16552927/623735) I just may have it.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the class itself as the decorator, so only its `__init__` is called.  Your `__call__` is never called.

Use an instance instead:

```
@decorators.prefix_model_name_with_filename()
```

About your updated question: A decorator can't change the actual name used to refer to an object in the enclosing namespace.  (You can brute-force it by sticking a new name into a particular namespace, but it's up to you to ensure that the namespace you put the name into is the one where the object was originally defined.)  The decorator syntax:

```
@deco
class Foo(object):
    ...
```

Is equivalent to

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
Foo = deco(Foo)
```

Note that the last line says `Foo =`, because the original class was defined with `class Foo`.  You can't change that.  The decorated object is always reassigned to the same name it originally had.

There are hackish ways to get around this.  You can make your decorator write a new name to the global namespace, or even look at the decorated object's `__module__` attribute and write a new name to that namespace.  However, this isn't really what decorators are for, and it's going to make your code confusing.  Decorators are for modifying/wrapping objects, not modifying the namespaces from which those objects are accessed.

Comment: That fixed my immediate error. ShipMeth.__name__ is now working (appropriately prefixed). However it doesn't affect the module's locals() dict key (the actual name of the class/type). So I'm still missing something.

Comment: Do I need to decorate the module somehow?

Comment: @hobs: See my updated answer.  You can't do that with a decorator (without ugly hacks).

Comment: I guess I'll just have the autocoder that's writing the class definitions to put the right names in the py files instead of prefixing all the classes with a decorator. The decorator attempt seems over-complicated in hindsight. Thanks for the reminder/education of what a decorator is and its limitations.